# Dirac, Weyl and Majorana Spinors

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, spinors, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

To get to the point - what's the defining differences between them? Alas, my current understanding of a spinor is limited. All I know is that they are used to describe fermions (?), but I'm not sure why?

Although I should probably grasp the above first, what is the difference between Dirac, Weyl and Majorana spinors? I know that there are similarities (as in overlaps) and that the Dirac spinor is a solution to the Dirac equation etc. But what's their mathematical differences, their purpose and their importance?

(It might be good to note that I'm coming from a string theory perspective. Plus I've exhausted Wikipedia here.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Recall a Dirac spinor which obeys the Dirac Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_\mu -m)\psi.$$

The Dirac spinor is a four-component spinor, but may be decomposed into a pair of two-component spinors, i.e. we propose

$$\psi = \left( \begin{array}{c} u_+\\ u_-\end{array}\right),$$

and the Dirac Lagrangian becomes,

$$\mathcal{L} = iu_{-}^{\dagger}\sigma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}u_{-} + iu_{+}^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}u_{+} -m(u^{\dagger}_{+}u_{-} + u_{-}^{\dagger}u_{+})$$

where $\sigma^{\mu} = (\mathbb{1},\sigma^{i})$ and $\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} = (\mathbb{1},-\sigma^{i})$ where $\sigma^{i}$ are the Pauli matrices and $i=1,..,3.$ The two-component spinors $u_{+}$ and $u_{-}$ are called Weyl or chiral spinors. In the limit $m\to 0$, a fermion can be described by a single Weyl spinor, satisfying e.g.

$$i\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}u_{+}=0.$$

Majorana fermions are similar to Weyl fermions; they also have two-components. But  they must satisfy a reality condition and they must be invariant under charge conjugation. When you expand a Majorana fermion, the Fourier coefficients (or operators upon canonical quantization) are real. In other words, a Majorana fermion $\psi_{M}$ may be written in terms of Weyl spinors as,

$$\psi_M = \left( \begin{array}{c} u_+\\ -i \sigma^2u^\ast_+\end{array}\right).$$

Majorana spinors are used frequently in supersymmetric theories. In the Wess-Zumino model - the simplest SUSY model - a supermultiplet is constructed from a complex scalar, auxiliary pseudo-scalar field, and Majorana spinor precisely because it has two degrees of freedom unlike a Dirac spinor. The action of the theory is simply,

$$S \sim - \int d^4x \left( \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu \phi^{\ast}\partial_\mu \phi + i \psi^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi + |F|^2 \right)$$

where $F$ is the auxiliary field, whose equations of motion set $F=0$ but is necessary on grounds of consistency due to the degrees of freedom off-shell and on-shell.

Comment: So am I right in saying all Majorana spinors are Weyl spinors, but not the other way around? And Weyl spinors, and therefore Majorana spinors as well, are subsets of Dirac spinors?

Comment: I think you got it the other way around. All Majorana spinors are constructed from Weyl spinors, but Weyl spinors are not Majorana spinors.

Comment: This is what I said?

Answer (score 4):

After you will learn more about spinors, you will see that all spinors belong to the $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right) + \left( 0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ representation of the $SL(2,C)$ group, which is the double cover of the lorentz group $SO(3,1)$. The idea is to find representations of a simply connected covering group which in this case is $SL(2,C)$, the local structure given by the lie algebraic commutation relation remains the same.

Spinorial equations allow to extract Lorentz-invariant subspaces in the overall space of $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right) + \left( 0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ representation.

Both Dirac and Majorana spinors belong to $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right) + \left( 0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ representation of $SL(2,C)$ group, but they are only *subspaces* of it. For instance, Majorana spinors are all electrically neutral (i.e. remain invariant under charge conjugation). Similarly, Dirac spinors are "magnetically neutral".

Weil spinors belong to either $\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ or $\left( 0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ subspaces. Unlike Dirac and Majorana spinors, they might be considered as 2-component spinors. But this is also a limitation, because some special Lorentz transformations cannot be applied to these spinors.

Comment: Your first line is another issue I've been struggling to comprehend for a while now. Care to explain what you mean by $(\frac{1}{2},0)+(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $SL(2,C)$? Representations just seem beyond me at the moment.

Comment: @Murod: Could you elaborate on what you mean by Dirac spinors are "magnetically neutral"?

Comment: @user13223423: The $so(3,1)$ lie algebra decomposes as $su(2)_L \oplus su(2)_R$. So any representation of $su(3,1)$ must be a tensor product of representations of the two subalgebras. Weyl spinors are in the "fundamental" rep of one of the $su(2)$ while they're in the trivial representation of the other. That is denoted by $({\frac{1}{2}}_L , 0_R)$ or the other way around. The Dirac and Majorana representations happen to be a linear combination of the two Weyl representations (with maybe other conditions).

Comment: There is a good explanation about representations of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ in Weinberg's book. @Siva, you mean direct sum, not tensor product. The direct sum of (1/2,0) and (0,1/2) is the Dirac spinors, but their tensor product is (1/2,1/2) which is the 4-vector representation.

As for the special Lorentz transformations, parity takes left-handed Weyl spinors to right-handed and the other way around.

Comment: Whoops! That was a bad slip on my part. Thanks for the correction @RobinEkman. It is indeed the direct sum.

Comment: @Murod: Shoudn't your first sentence read double cover of $SO(3,1)$, spinors are representations of $SL(2,C)$ which is the double cover of $SO(3,1)$ - the lorentz group also called projective representations of the lorentz group for the same reason.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac: You are absolutely right. But I did not write that "double cover", someone edited my post.