# Connection between Pauli matrices and Quaternions?

Tags: dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices

reading [this sentence from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices):

*The Pauli matrices (after multiplication by i to make them anti-Hermitian) also generate transformations in the sense of Lie algebras: the matrices iσ1, iσ2, iσ3 form a basis for the real Lie algebra, which exponentiates to the special unitary group SU(2). The algebra generated by the three matrices σ1, σ2, σ3 is isomorphic to the Clifford algebra R^3, and the (unital associative) algebra generated by iσ1, iσ2, iσ3 is effectively identical (isomorphic) to that of quaternions.*

Does it mean that:

1. Pauli matrices are just Quaternions, and
2. [Dirac Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) is simply quaternion-version of Schroedinger equation? (just because some phase rotates in 4D not just 2D space)

I know this is more-or-less the same question as [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714043/) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516010/), but the answer was too theoretical. I would like somebody to tell me this **in layman's terms**.

I'm quite familiar with quaternions from programming 3D engines in games where are used to represent 3D rotations. But what Pauli matrices represent was always a mystery to me. So if somebody make this connection (without using to much obscure language) it would make the things more clear and didactic from start.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is there this relationship between quaternions and Pauli matrices?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271419/2451).

Comment: sorry but from to answer to  "Why is there this relationship between quaternions and Pauli matrices?" I don't understand virutaly anything. I really want some aswer in "layman's terms" ... maybe simple Yes or No would be better answer from me.